# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the PublicKeysService (?, ConfigService). Please make sure that the argument HttpService at index [0] is available

Tags: nestjs

I have seen a couple of articles related to this error here, but I still need some guidance on exactly what is going on because I have tried to make `HttpService` a part of the current `PublicKeysModule` and i have tried to import it within the `PublicKeysModule`.

This is my current public keys module:

```
import { Module } from "@nestjs/common";
import { PublicKeysService } from "./public-keys.service";
import { PublicKeysController } from "./public-keys.controller";

@Module({
  providers: [PublicKeysService],
  controllers: [PublicKeysController],
})
export class PublicKeysModule {}
```

The `HttpService` is coming from Axios and it's imported in the public keys service:

```
    import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
    import { HttpService } from "@nestjs/axios";
    import { ConfigService } from "@nestjs/config";
    import { MessageResponseDto } from "../../../shared-dtos";
    import { ConfigService } from "./dtos/public-key-response.dto";

    @Injectable()
    export class PublicKeysService {
       constructor(
          private _httpService: HttpService,
          private _config: ConfigService
       ) {}
    }
```

I tried adding `HttpModule` as `imports: []` in the public keys module as I learned in another post that it should be `HttpModule` and not `HttpService`, but when I did that, the error did not go away.

Now when I used `HttpService` in the `imports: [HttpService]` for public key module. I get a totally new error saying:

> Please make sure that the argument AXIOS_INSTANCE_TOKEN at index [0]
> is available in the HttpService context

So I am stumped here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `imports: [HttpModule]` in your `PublicKeysModule`. That's what gives access to the `HttpService` in the context of the module.

Comment: McDaniel, that's weird because I tried that and I still get that same error in terminal. Now if I add `HttpService` instead of `HttpModule` to the `imports: []` in the public keys module then I get another error saying ensure AXIOS_INSTANCE_TOKEN is available in the HttpService context.

Comment: Don't add services to the `imports`. What's the error when you have `HttpModule` in the imports?

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the HTTPModule in your PublicKeyModule imports array.

```
import { HttpModule } from "@nestjs/axios";
import { Module } from "@nestjs/common";
import { PublicKeysService } from "./public-keys.service";
import { PublicKeysController } from "./public-keys.controller";

@Module({
  imports: [HttpModule],
  providers: [PublicKeysService],
  controllers: [PublicKeysController],
})
export class PublicKeysModule {}
```

Here is a detailed article about how the HTTP Module works [How to use Axios in NestJs](https://www.codewithvlad.com/blog/how-to-use-axios-in-nestjs)